# pImpl, scope and hidden data members

Tags: c++

Let's say I have an object of type `B`, and call `B.foo()`, where `foo()` is a method defined in `A` and has not been redefined in `B`. `A::foo()` has the line `impl->foo()`.

**When we call B.foo(), does it use A::impl or B::impl?**

Scott Meyers' 3rd Edition Guide to Effective C++ explains the hiding concept associated with inheritance, such that the compiler checks the local namespace, then class namespace, then works its way up the hierarchy, but I'm unclear what happens here, I don't know whether the 'initial' namespace checked is that of `B` or of `A`, since the object is of type `B` but the method is in `A`'s namespace.

My own tests seem to indicate that when `B.foo()` is called, and `A::foo()` is executed, it looks at the `impl` variable in `A`, not `B`.

```
class Aimpl;
class Bimpl;

struct A {
    Aimpl* impl;
    int foo();
};

struct B : public A{
    Bimpl* impl;
};


struct Aimpl {
    int foo(){
        return -1;
    }
};

int A::foo(){
    return impl->foo();
}

struct Bimpl{
    int foo(){
        return 5;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B x;
    x.foo();
}
```

Comment: Not a bad question, but some code examples would make it easier to answer.

Comment: It's often a lot better to express your problem in terms of code than by writing huge paragraphs about your code. There's a lot of text here to absorb, and yet I don't think it's specific enough about the nature of the functions in question. Is that a `static` method?

Comment: I've added some code, let me know if there is any additional clarification necessary, and thanks in advance for any time you spend thinking about this.

Comment: As your tests show, `A::impl` will be used in `A::foo`.

Comment: Your `B` class does not have a `foo()` method (although it has a pointer `impl`, never initialized, to a class type `Bimpl` that do has foo()). So, when `x.foo()` is executed `x` uses its parent `A::foo()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When we call `B.foo()`, does it use `A::impl` or `B::impl`?

It uses `A::impl`.

---

When the `x.foo()` call is made it is`A::foo()` that is called.

The `Bimpl* impl` pointer in `B` does hide the `impl` in `A`, but when calling `foo` in `A` the inheriting class `B` is not visible to `A`.